# Examples of "convolution weights"

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, convolution

Let $X,R$ be semigroups. For the sake of this thread a *convolution weight* $w : X \rightsquigarrow R$ is a function $w : X^2\to R$ such that:

$$w(s\cdot t, r) \cdot w(s,t) = w(s,t\cdot r)\cdot w(t,r)$$

Examples include constant functions $X^2\to R$, indicator functions or e.g. the "binomial weight":

$$w : \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^2 \to R, (s,t) \mapsto \binom{s+t}{t} = \binom{s+t}{s}$$

where $R$ is the multiplicative monoid of a rig (or ring).

> What are other (interesting) examples of such functions?

---

Motivation:

Suppose $R$ is a rig.
Given a convolution weight $w$, define its *associated convolution* $* : (R^X)^2 \to R^X$ by:

$$(f*g)(x) := \sum_{s\cdot t = x} w(s,t)\cdot f(s)\cdot g(t)$$

Then $(R^X,+,*)$ is a rg ("rig without identity"). This includes familiar convolutions like discrete convolution, Dirichlet convolution or binomial convolution.

Comment: How about $(f{*}g)(x) := \sum_{s\cdot t=x} B(f(s),g(t))$, where $B:R\times R\to R$  is bilinear (or some type of inner product)?

Comment: Also, depending on your semigroup $X$, you might have to resort to taking an integral rather than a sum.  In this case, could one think of the information of the weight being included in the choice of measure defining the convolution?